# How to fix this "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'UIElement'" error in c#

Tags: c#

i'm currenlty making working on a piece of code on how to work with C#. So this is probably a very easy question for real programmers to work around.

I've litterly tried everything. But i'm past searching, and I'm just curious on what the issue is here. I'd be thrilled if someone could point this out for me. Thanks on forehand!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWbRG.jpg

```
       private void ButtonDraw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            MakeRectangle(drawingArea, color, 10, 20, 20);
            MakeRectangle(drawingArea, color, 10, 20, 40);
            MakeRectangle(drawingArea, color, 10, 20, 60);

        }

        private void MakeRectangle(Canvas drawing, SolidColorBrush brushcolor, double xPos, double yPos, double size)
        {
            Rectangle vierkant = new Rectangle();
            vierkant.Height = size;
            vierkant.Width = size;
            vierkant.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            vierkant.Stroke = brushcolor;
            drawing.Children.Add(MakeRectangle);

        }
```

Comment: `MakeRectangle` is a method. `drawing.Children` presumably expects a `UIElement`. Unless `drawing.Children` is a list where each item is a `delegate` with the same arguments as the `MakeRectangle` method, you can't add it to the list. Did you intend to add `vierkant`?

Comment: Either try: `drawing.Children.Add(vierkant);` or `drawing.Children.Add(MakeRectangle(drawingArea, color, 10, 20, 20);` both would work, as @John said you need to pass the object of type UIElement and not the method

Comment: This also looks like it will recurse forever and throw a `StackOverflowException`. My guess is that you're a C# beginner, perhaps you would benefit from running through some tutorials before asking questions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the vierkant Rectangle object into the drawing.Children.Add() method, see below:

```
private void MakeRectangle(Canvas drawing, SolidColorBrush brushcolor, double xPos, double yPos, double size)
        {
            Rectangle vierkant = new Rectangle();
            vierkant.Height = size;
            vierkant.Width = size;
            vierkant.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            vierkant.Stroke = brushcolor;
            drawing.Children.Add(vierkant );

        }
```

Comment: Oh my god, so lame! I should have known. Thank you so much for pointing this out for me.